# Generalized Gabriel's Horn proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, terminology, proof-explanation

I'm looking for a way to find for what values of r the curve $\dfrac 1{x^r}$ between $0$ to $\infty$ rotated about the $x$-axis  has finite volume and surface. I found this , but I'm not sure what the OP meant by "comparison theorem".

> If one makes the corresponding "Gabriel's Horn" by rotating  the region under $\dfrac{1}{x^p}$ from $x=1$ to $x=\infty$ around the
> $x$-axis, then:
>
> 1. The volume is finite iff $p>\frac{1}{2}$
> 2. The surface area is finite iff $p > 1$ so in particular
> 3. The Horn has finite volume and infinite surface area for any $p$ between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$, where $p$ cannot be $\frac{1}{2}$ but
>    it can be $1$.
>
> The proof is simply several uses of the comparison theorem.

Comment: (1.) I think the comparison theorem here refers to **limit comparison tests**.
(2.) Exactly on what portion of $1/x^r$ are you looking for? Specifically, what is the region and what is the axis of rotation to find the volume and surface area?

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to.mention it. I'm interested in [0, infinity)

Comment: Ok. Now how about the limit comparison tests, do you have any background that?

Comment: Not really unfortunately. But now that I know what I'm looking for I guess I can go read about it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This comparison theorem is the theorem that $\int_1^\infty 1/x^p$ converges if $p>1$ and diverges if $p\leq 1$.

In the case of the Gabriel's horn function, the surface area is proportional to the radius $r=1/x^p$ integrated from 1 to infinity, $\int_1^\infty 1/x^p$, but the volume is proportional to $\pi r^2$,  as the radius is rotated around the axis, so the volume is proportional to the integral of $\int_1^\infty 1/x^{2p}$.

If $p= 1$ then the surface area integral $\int_1^\infty {1\over x} dx$ diverges, but the volume integral is just $\int_1^\infty {1\over x^2} dx= 1$

Comment: I think rather it is using the tests on more complicated expressions to determine convergence through comparison to $1/x^p$, you should clarify this

Comment: @FShrike The volume of the Gabriel's horn shape is proportional to the integral of $1/x^{2p}$ and the surface area is proportional to the integral of $1/x^p$. We know that $\int_0^\infty 1/x$ diverges but $\int_0^\infty 1/x^{1.1}$ converges. The Gabriel's horn shape is a deliberate case of a pathological shape which has infinite surface area and finite volume. But I'm not sure what the theorem is called which is being used.

Comment: My answer was very messy with many errors and omissions, hopefully it is now improved.